# TWIG PersistentCollection could not be converted to string: output data on a table from OneToMany - ManyToOne entity

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to display data of each match in a table like this one:

```
img1 | name1 | score1 | score2 | name2 | img2 | date | statut_id
```

Here is how I would do it in sql:

```
SELECT j1.image AS img1, j1.name AS name1, s1.score AS score1, s2.score AS score2, j2.name AS name2, j2.image AS img2, m.date AS date, m.statut_id FROM jouster j1, jouster j2, matchs m, score s1, score s2 WHERE j1.id = s1.jouster_id AND m.id = s1.matchs_id AND j2.id = s2.jouster_id AND m.id = s2.matchs_id AND m.jouster1_id = j1.id AND m.jouster2_id = j2.id
```

I want to do it with the "symfony way" but i'm not used to it

I have an issue with scores. When I try to access to the score of each jousters I get this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string").

match.html.twig

```
{%  for match in matchs %}
    {{match.jouster1.image}}
    {{match.jouster1.name}}
    {{match.jouster1.scores}}
    -
    {{match.jouster2.scores}}
    {{match.jouster2.name}}
    {{match.jouster2.image}}
    {{match.date | date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}

    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

MatchController.php

```
 /**
 * @Route("/match", name="match")
 */
public function match() {
    $matchs = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Matchs::class)->findAll();

    return $this->render('page/match.html.twig', [
        'matchs' => $matchs
        ]);
}
```

Matchs.php

```
class Matchs {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Jouster", inversedBy="jouster2")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $jouster1;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Jouster", inversedBy="matchAsJouster2")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $jouster2;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Score", mappedBy="matchs", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $scores;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Statut", inversedBy="matchs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $statut;

    *************************
    *** getters & setters ***
    *************************

    /**
     * @return Collection|Score[]
     */
    public function getScores(): Collection
    {
        return $this->scores;
    }

    public function addScore(Score $score): self
    {
        if (!$this->scores->contains($score)) {
            $this->scores[] = $score;
            $score->setMatchs($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Score.php

```
class Score
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", nullable=true)
     */
    private $score;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Jouster", inversedBy="scores")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $jouster;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Matchs", inversedBy="scores")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $matchs;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getScore(): ?int
    {
        return $this->score;
    }

    public function setScore(int $score): self
    {
        $this->score = $score;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getJouster(): ?Jouster
    {
        return $this->jouster;
    }

    public function setJouster(?Jouster $jouster): self
    {
        $this->jouster = $jouster;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMatchs(): ?Matchs
    {
        return $this->matchs;
    }

    public function setMatchs(?Matchs $matchs): self
    {
        $this->matchs = $matchs;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Jouster.php

```
    /**
 * @return Collection|Score[]
 */
public function getScores(): Collection
{
    return $this->scores;
}

public function addScore(Score $score): self
{
    if (!$this->scores->contains($score)) {
        $this->scores[] = $score;
        $score->setJouster($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeScore(Score $score): self
{
    if ($this->scores->contains($score)) {
        $this->scores->removeElement($score);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($score->getJouster() === $this) {
            $score->setJouster(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

EDIT:
I had to do a loop in order to display matchs scores.

```
{%  for match in matchs %}
    {{match.jouster1.image}}
    {{match.jouster1.name}}

    {% for score in match.scores%}
    {{score.score}}
    {% endfor %}

    {{match.jouster2.name}}
    {{match.jouster2.image}}
    {{match.date | date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}
```

Comment: `scores` is a collection, so you would need to loop that attribute in order to display all the available scores

Comment: It did the trick thanks !

Answer (score 1):

as [DarkBee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446594/darkbee) stated in he's comment.

The error is clearly explained in the error message itself:

> PersistentCollection could not be converted to string

Meaning, you had twig try to output something, which was actually not 1 thing, but a collection of things. (Scores in your case)

Comment: Although it is the correct answer, one should note that the confusion comes from Symfony's error message which points to the *render* method in Controller instead of the culprit line in twig.